# Faster way to filter zip code prefix errors using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with zip code and state columns (among others). It's large but not terrible (4M rows, 70 columns) but it just takes forever to filter erroneous observations. Specifically, I'm trying to drop observations where zip code does not add up with states (e.g., NJ zip codes start with 0 but many zip codes in the data start with 7). Here's my current approach, but there must be a faster way I believe. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

```
df_clean <- df_tmp %>%  
  filter(!(startsWith(zip, c("7", "8")) & state == "NJ")) %>%
  filter(!(startsWith(zip, c("0", "1")) & state == "FL")) %>%
  filter(!(startsWith(zip, "4") & state == "ME")) %>%
  filter(!(startsWith(zip, c("1", "2")) & state == "MA")) %>%
  filter(!(startsWith(zip, "6") & state == "CT"))
```

I hope it's self-explanatory, but let me know if a sample dataset would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I think a faster approach would be to create a lookup table for the correct starting zip code digit for each state, then join that table with your data frame. Then filter by all rows where starting digit == the correct starting digit for that state. That would execute more quickly and also not rely on you manually entering digits for individual states.

Comment: That's a good idea. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You could use the information here https://smartystreets.com/docs/zip-codes-101 to create the first-digit lookup table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more programmatic approach that involves creating a lookup table with the correct starting digit by state, joining it with your data, and removing all rows where the starting digit doesn't match the expected digit for that state.

```
digits_by_state <- data.frame(state = c("NJ", "FL", "ME", "MA", "CT"), 
                              correct_digit = c(0,3,0,0,0))

df_clean <- df_tmp %>%
  mutate(starting_digit = as.integer(substr(zip, 1, 1))) %>%
  left_join(digits_by_state) %>%
  filter(starting_digit == correct_digit)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, if the dataframe is large, every filter will remove a bit of it, then pass a still large dataset on to the next filter, so it gets slow.

If you could combine all your conditions in one filter expression, it would run much faster. Like this:

```
df_clean <- df_tmp %>%  
  filter(
    !(startsWith(zip, c("7", "8")) & state == "NJ") |
    !(startsWith(zip, c("0", "1")) & state == "FL") |
    !(startsWith(zip, "4") & state == "ME") |
    !(startsWith(zip, c("1", "2")) & state == "MA") |
    !(startsWith(zip, "6") & state == "CT")
  )
```

Do not bother to surround the & expressions with (), before the |, because the | has lower priority anyway. This way your expressions become more readable.